# Python: if, elif, else. Error: SyntaxError: bad input on line 6 in main.py

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, save

I have a bug I'm trying to eradicate for a project I'm working on.
SyntaxError: bad input on line 6 in main.py

I intend to give credit where credit is due.. Whoever helps me solve this can work out how they want to receive the comment in my code.

I don't know what to try.
EDIT: https://trinket.io

```
    if save == 'y':
      filename = 'storage.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
          json.dump(box, f_obj)
    print(storage)
    elif save == 'n':
      input('another box?')
    else:
      print('i don't understand your input')
```

I want to save variables into retrievable storage when it powers back on.
When a user types "y", the variable will save.
When a user types "n", the user will be asked if they need to create another box.
When a user types anything else, they will be told "i don't understand..."

Comment: As indicated below.  White Space characters ARE significant in python

Answer (score 1):

When you have an if/elif/else block, all the code from the `if` to the final `else` must be indented underneath those statements, like so:

```
if a == 1:
    # do this
    # and this
elif a == 2:
    # do that
    # and that
else:
    # do the other thing
    # and the other thing
```

But in your code, the `with open` line and the `print` line are not indented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This didn't solve the SyntaxError: bad input on line 6 in main.py I'm testing my code on https://trinket.io/embed/python/33e5c3b81b#.XVJy1PZFzid

Comment: Posting your code as an external link just makes it harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if save == 'y':
      filename = 'storage.json'
      with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(box, f_obj)
      print(storage)
    elif save == 'n':
      input('another box?')
    else:
      print('i dont understand your input')
```

can you try this once?
I was getting an error at "don't", as it was confusing the quotes in the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

- Indentation is not correct.
- You are mixing quote symbols: 'I don't...' . So your string is in fact ending before the t. Replace the single quotes by double quotes and keep the apostrophe as it is.